# Adding Tabbar Controller Icon IPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, icons, nib

I am adding a viewController to a TabBarController.  When I add a ViewController from the custom class and Nib, it''s icon does not show up in the tabBar.

If I initialize like this the icon does not show up.

```
viewController = [[FlashCardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlashCardViewController"  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

But creating a generic viewController works.

```
viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil  bundle:nil];
```

Here we add the image and title.

```
viewController.title = @"Quiz";
viewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"magnifying-glass.png"];
```

How can I get the icon to display if load from a NIB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the call to the `tabBarItem.image` setter inside the custom view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
@implementation FlashCardViewController
//...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"magnifying-glass.png"];
}
//...
@end
```

**Edit:** OK, so that didn't work. Try:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"magnifying-glass.png"];
    self.tabBarItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"string"
                                                     image:image
                                                       tag:0] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I thought for sure that your suggestion would work, but still no icon.  Any other ideas Tim?

Comment: Maybe initialize the entire tab bar item yourself? See edited code above.

Comment: Thanks.  I was overwriting the image and title in another spot.   This actually works!   Only one problem here is that until you click on the tab to load the view, the tabBarItem has no icon or label.  Any ideas?

Comment: Move the code from `viewDidLoad` into `initWithNibName:bundle:`?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing in [NSBundle mainbundle] to the FlashCardViewController init?  Usually you just pass in nil - as per your working example...

Comment: I thought that might be a problem and I switched it to nil but there was no difference so I stuck with what I had before.   I had been loading FlashCardViewController by itself - not into a TabBarController - and it worked great.

I am not sure why I pass NSBundle mainbubdle.  What does that specify?